# why is mysql handling the column as primary key?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When adding new data to the mysql table I always get the error:

```
Duplicate entry '2026-06-20' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Although the field "flightDate" is neither primarykey nor is it set to unique as you can see in img[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLx6m.png). what else can be the problem?

[image: table setup]

Comment: It's hard to read the image, can you replace it with `show create table <tablename>;`?

Comment: What statement are you using to insert into this table? Can you reduce your problem to an example that demonstrates this for others?

Comment: And can you show us which INSERT command is failing?

Comment: Googling "for key 'PRIMARY'" throws up a shedload of results on StackOverflow that look similar to this one. I haven't the time right now to read through them all, but I suspect one contains an answer for you.

Comment: My german isn't very good, but I'm guessing Primärschlüssel means primary key and by the looks of it, the only field where the the Primärschlüssel text isn't clickable, is the flightDate field. Are you sure the primary key for the table isn't a compound key based on flightDate, planeID and pilot? It would make sense to me.

Comment: INSERT INTO flights_temp (flightID , flightDate, planeID, pilot) VALUES(322, 06-12-2012, "B737","somePilotsName")

fails and the property of "primary key" (the yellow key) is only set to the flightID field

Comment: Like Barmar pointed out, we need to see the DDL.

Comment: Are there any triggers on that table?

Comment: thats strange. the DDL shows obviously that the flightDate field ist primaryKey. 

--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `flights_temp` (
  `flightID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `flightDate` date NOT NULL,
  `planeID` text NOT NULL,
  `pilot` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`flightDate`),
  UNIQUE KEY `flightDate` (`flightDate`),
  UNIQUE KEY `flightID` 

but the GUI of phpMyAdmin tells something else with the yellow key icon set on flightID

Answer (score 0):

Your `flightDate` is in PRIMARY KEY or COMPOSITE KEY most probably. Check your indexes. `flightID` should be the key, but it is not as seen in your picture.

Comment: Here is a n larger screenshot. And yes, "PRIMÄRSCHLÜSSEL" = "PRIMARY KEY" ;)
The image/phpmyadmin GUI tells me that flightID is the primary key. That's what i want. But in fact (as i could see in the DDL) the flightDate is primary Key.


[1]https://www.dropbox.com/s/l2es9m8kq5x0pyg/primKey.PNG

Comment: Yellow key means that this column is NOT in the index yet. [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6je5acqz8qbo98j/phpMyAdmin.PNG)

Comment: so then my next and maybe last question is, how can i change the primary of a table that i created before? is that possible via the GUI or only via a SQL command?

Comment: Yes, you can via GUI also - press `+Indexes` (`+Indizes`) as shown [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l2bhuq6y15mltsc/indexes.PNG) and you can edit your primary key or add other keys as you want.